# How many ways are there to 10 people sit in a row of 10 chairs if exactly 5 of them are sited on chairs with a number on ticket?

Tags: combinatorics

I thought that the result is ${10 \choose 5} \cdot 5!$ (first we select people that are sited properly and the rest are sited arbitrary on the free places). But an official solution is 11088. Any ideas?

Ok, I figured out. I'll leave the problem on site anyway.

Comment: Ah, I think now that I know were I missed the solution. Those 5 which are seated arbitrary, they should not sit on chairs with the numbers of ticket they buy, i.e. there is no fixed point in permutation of those 5.

Comment: So for those 5 we have (use PIE): $$5!-4\cdot 4! +10\cdot 3!-10\cdot 2!+5\cdot 1! -1 =44$$ posibilites and not $5! =120$. Thus result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom{10}{5}$ ways to choose those that sit in their assigned chairs and $\mathcal{D}(5)=44$ ways to derange the other $5$, so you get $\binom{10}{5}\mathcal{D}(5)=11088$, where $\mathcal{D}(n)$ is the number of [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of a set of $n$ elements.